# How to kill nonexistent program process

Tags: linux, kill, ps

Some days ago, I installed `shellinabox` in my ubuntu 16.04, since I do not use it anymore, so I uninstalled it via `sudo apt-get remove shellinabox`. After uninstalled successfully, I checked the process and found the shellinabox process is still there, if I killed this process, a few seconds later, it shows again.

```
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep shellinabox
ldh        5178  10185  0 14:10 pts/21   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shellinabox
nobody   113899 113881  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 shellinaboxd -t -s /:LOGIN -s /python:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python -s /ipython:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython -s /python3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python3 -s /ipython3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython3 -s /cling:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/local/bin/cling --static-file=styles.css:/usr/local/share/shellinabox/shellinabox.css --user-css=Tomorrow Light:+/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-light.css,Tomorrow Dark:-/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-dark.css
nobody   113990 113899  0 13:56 ?        00:00:00 shellinaboxd -t -s /:LOGIN -s /python:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python -s /ipython:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython -s /python3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python3 -s /ipython3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython3 -s /cling:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/local/bin/cling --static-file=styles.css:/usr/local/share/shellinabox/shellinabox.css --user-css=Tomorrow Light:+/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-light.css,Tomorrow Dark:-/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-dark.css
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ kill -9 113899
-bash: kill: (113899) - Operation not permitted
ldh@ldh55:~$ sudo !!
sudo kill -9 113899
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep shellinabox
ldh        5637  10185  0 14:10 pts/21   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shellinabox
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep shellinabox
ldh        5754  10185  0 14:10 pts/21   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shellinabox
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep shellinabox
nobody     5693   5675  1 14:10 ?        00:00:00 shellinaboxd -t -s /:LOGIN -s /python:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python -s /ipython:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython -s /python3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python3 -s /ipython3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython3 -s /cling:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/local/bin/cling --static-file=styles.css:/usr/local/share/shellinabox/shellinabox.css --user-css=Tomorrow Light:+/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-light.css,Tomorrow Dark:-/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-dark.css
nobody     5758   5693  0 14:10 ?        00:00:00 shellinaboxd -t -s /:LOGIN -s /python:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python -s /ipython:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython -s /python3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python3 -s /ipython3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython3 -s /cling:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/local/bin/cling --static-file=styles.css:/usr/local/share/shellinabox/shellinabox.css --user-css=Tomorrow Light:+/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-light.css,Tomorrow Dark:-/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-dark.css
ldh        5792  10185  0 14:10 pts/21   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shellinabox
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ sudo ls -l /proc/5693/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 0 Sep  5 14:11 attr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 autogroup
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 auxv
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 cgroup
--w------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 clear_refs
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 cmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 comm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 coredump_filter
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 cwd -> /home/shell
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 environ
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 exe -> /usr/bin/shellinaboxd
dr-x------ 2 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 fd
dr-x------ 2 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 fdinfo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 gid_map
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 io
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 limits
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 loginuid
dr-x------ 2 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 map_files
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 maps
-rw------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 mem
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 mountinfo
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 mounts
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 mountstats
dr-xr-xr-x 5 nobody nogroup 0 Sep  5 14:11 net
dr-x--x--x 2 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 ns
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 numa_maps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 oom_adj
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 oom_score
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 oom_score_adj
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 pagemap
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 personality
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 projid_map
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 root -> /
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 sched
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 schedstat
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 sessionid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 setgroups
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 smaps
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 stack
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 stat
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 statm
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 status
-r-------- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 syscall
dr-xr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 0 Sep  5 14:11 task
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 timers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:10 uid_map
-r--r--r-- 1 root   root    0 Sep  5 14:11 wchan
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ ll /usr/bin/shellinaboxd
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/shellinaboxd': No such file or directory
ldh@ldh55:~$
```

Comment: That's extremely strange. `-9` should kill it dead (and apparently it does), which means something is relaunching it, which means it can't really be uninstalled. I would check two things: `ls -l /usr/bin/shellinaboxd` to make sure it's really gone, and `pstree -p 113899` (or whatever its PID is) to see what keeps relaunching it.

Comment: In the above log you see that the new (relaunched) shellinaboxd was launched by the parent process 5675. Just go an check what that process is and why it relaunches your shellinaboxd.

Comment: Thanks, @Amadan and pitseeker, finally, I found the answer, it was related to the shellinabox process which runs in the docker container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Amadan and @pitseeker, I checked the pstree of the parent process, and find that the strange process maybe the shellinabox process which in the docker container, Since I also run the shellinabox docker container.

```
ldh@ldh55:~$ pstree -p 5675
docker-containe(5675)─┬─shellinaboxd(5693)───shellinaboxd(5758)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5676)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5677)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5678)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5679)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5680)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5681)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5682)
                      ├─{docker-containe}(5683)
                      └─{docker-containe}(5757)
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep 5675
root       5675  15288  0 14:10 ?        00:00:00 docker-containerd-shim a865ae1d7398f23f8c3e484bce9817522b57a5f68d37a6756e812c93e72e4d1c /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/a865ae1d7398f23f8c3e484bce9817522b57a5f68d37a6756e812c93e72e4d1c docker-runc
nobody     5693   5675  0 14:10 ?        00:00:00 shellinaboxd -t -s /:LOGIN -s /python:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python -s /ipython:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython -s /python3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/python3 -s /ipython3:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/bin/ipython3 -s /cling:shell:shell:HOME:/usr/local/bin/cling --static-file=styles.css:/usr/local/share/shellinabox/shellinabox.css --user-css=Tomorrow Light:+/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-light.css,Tomorrow Dark:-/usr/local/share/shellinabox/theme-tomorrow-dark.css
ldh      104903  90695  0 15:11 pts/22   00:00:00 grep --color=auto 5675
ldh@ldh55:~$
ldh@ldh55:~$ docker ps|grep shellinabox
a865ae1d7398        9d6d77a31ef3                                             "shellinaboxd -t -..."   5 months ago        Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5200->4200/tcp                          shellinaboxshell_shellinabox-shell_1
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ docker stop a865ae1d7398
a865ae1d7398
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$ ps -ef|grep shellinabox
ldh      115468  90695  0 15:17 pts/22   00:00:00 grep --color=auto shellinabox
ldh@ldh55:~$ 
ldh@ldh55:~$
```